# Replacing Rails ERB template with Vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2

I have this bizarre idea that how can we replace the Rails `erb` templating with `vue`. I think even the simplest of the sites today are data driven and want to be reactive. For people like me who are boilerplate averse.

I can do this with new Rails 5.1 but with the following limitations:

- The naturally available `@variables` are not present in js files, so I have to pass them as data attributes, use Gon gem or make another ajax request.
- The `/= require` syntax can be replaced with new `ES2015` imports, this will allow for a more modular design of the system.

I would like to know if someone has attempted to do this or has ideas on how this can be achieved.

Comment: While this certainly is an interesting question it is slightly too broad and therefore off-topic for Stackoverflow. If you couldn narrow it down with a code sample and show some obstacles you're facing it would be a better fit for the site.

Comment: @Iceman any suggestion what will be the right place to get some idea on this question?

Comment: Rails on reddit is quite active, might also try the rails mailing list.

Comment: See Nuxt. This can sit beside a Rails-powered API. You'll still have issues integrating the two as suggested in your question, but this separation may be a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

Gitlab has a rails backend and has adopted Vue for their frontend views.

The gist is they compartmentalise each feature per folder, and each folder has it's own Vue architecture. They serve the data needed for Vue component initialization in `data-*` attributes in haml files.

You can find out more here:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/fe_guide/vue.html#components-stores-and-services
- https://about.gitlab.com/2017/11/09/gitlab-vue-one-year-later/